# how can I get data from wordpress to react native app using graphql

Tags: wordpress, react-native, graphql, expo

I just try to use data from wordpress site to mobile app with graphql
from wordpress side I reach to the uri of site "http://10.0.2.2:10005/graphql" after install graphql plugin
from app side I did these steps
in app.js

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri:'http://10.0.2.2:10005/graphql/'
})

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
     <Drawer/>
   </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

in another screen

```
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default function IndiviOffers() {
return(
    <Query query={gql`
    {
         posts {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }        
    }
    `}>
        {({ loading, error, data })=>{
            console.log(data)

            
    return (
        <View >
            <Text>Your Offers</Text>
        </View>
    )
        }}
    </Query>
)
}
```

but I got that error Network error: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Comment: I use react native expo with wp-graphql I am new in this so I didn't know how to solve this issue , no cors for react native with wp-graphql

Comment: check (debug) full network response - not a json?

Comment: yes the response not json but I can't get the error on fetch data

Comment: different kind/level of errors ... not a valid graphql response (should be json)

Comment: I know that but I don't know how to update mentioned code to solve this error

Comment: check gepahiql/playground request - compare query (brackets), use valid/tested query